# Append value to a list which in nested dictionary

Tags: python

Basically I need to populate `d3` from `d2` and `d1`

```
d1 = {'Spain':['Madrid,'Barcelona'],'France':['Paris','Nice'],'Germany':['Dortmund','Berlin']}
d2 = {'Madrid':[1,2]'Barcelona':[2],'Paris':[3,4],'Nice':[4],'Dortmund':[5],'Berlin':[6]}
```

Desired output `d3` is as follows:

```
d3 = {'Spain':{'Madrid':[1,2]},{'Barcelona':[2]},'France':{'Paris':[3,4]},{'Nice':[4]},'Germany':{'Dortmund':{[5]},{'Berlin':[6]}}
```

I tried following but no luck, I am stuck

```
l = []
def getKeysByValue(dictOfElements, valueToFind):
    listOfKeys = list()
    listOfItems = dictOfElements.items()
    for item  in listOfItems:
    if item[1] == valueToFind:
        listOfKeys.append(item[0])
    return listOfKeys

for i in d2.keys():
    for j in d1.values():
        if i in j:
            name = str(getKeysByValue(d1,j))
            l.append({i:name2})
            d3[name] = l
print(d3)
```

Comment: Your dicts are not well formed: I assume that the second key in `d2` should be `'Barcelona'`, but that key does not follow a comma. Your output dict has no second key. I can make some assumptions but ...

Comment: You have some indentation errors, as well, which are probably only an issue with the way you tried to copy the code into SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to achieve this.

```
d1 = {'Spain': ['Madrid','Barcelona'],
      'France': ['Paris','Nice'],
      'Germany': ['Dortmund','Berlin']}

d2 = {'Madrid': [1,2],
      'Barcelona': [2],
      'Paris': [3,4],
      'Nice': [4],
      'Dortmund': [5],
      'Berlin':[6]}

d3 = {k: {city: d2[city] for city in v} for k, v in d1.items()}
```

It is iterating through the keys and values of `d1`. For every key, the value is a dictionary with each element in the value list as the key, and the `d2` value of that key as the value.

Comment: i and range are redundant. You could just iterate over the list items.

Comment: That is true. I'll change it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create `d3` like this:

```
d1 = {'Spain':['Madrid','Barcelona'],'France':['Paris','Nice'],'Germany':['Dortmund','Berlin']}

d2 = {'Madrid':[1,2],'Barcelona':[2],'Paris':[3,4],'Nice':[4],'Dortmund':[5],'Berlin':[6]}


d3 = {country:{city:d2[city] for city in cities} for (country,cities) in d1.items()}

print(d3)
```

Output:

```
{'Spain': {'Madrid': [1, 2], 'Barcelona': [2]}, 'France': {'Paris': [3, 4], 'Nice': [4]}, 'Germany': {'Dortmund': [5], 'Berlin': [6]}}
```

I have taken the liberty of correcting your data sources.

Comment: Special note, this supports lookup with d3['Spain']['Barcelona'] It's a pretty common way of nesting dictionaries. Note the use of good variable names where possible. (This could have been done in a loop just the same, but if you do python you need to see the equivalent loop in the comprehension syntax, and prefer comprehension)

Answer (score -1):

d1 = {'Spain':['Madrid','Barcelona'],'France':['Paris','Nice'],'Germany':['Dortmund','Berlin']}

d2 = {'Madrid':[1,2], 'Barcelona':[2],'Paris':[3,4],'Nice':[4],'Dortmund':[5],'Berlin':[6]}
d3 = {}

for k, v in d1.items():

```
data = {}

    for item in v:

        if item in d2:    #  to escape from an KeyError from d2 dictionary

            data[item] = d2[item]

 d3[k] = data
```